# TreeView selects Root as selectedItem on double click event

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I am working on a WPF application with a tree view control. I created event for double click event. But whenever I double click a TreeViewItem root element is selected.

Here is XAML

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TreeViewItem" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<TreeView 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TreeViewItem}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Hosts}"
    MouseDoubleClick="TreeView_MouseDoubleClick">
```

And here is my code behind.

```
private void TreeView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = sender.SelectedItem;
}
```

And here is my TreeView structure Example

```
CountryA
    CityA
         Street1
         Street2
    CityB
         Street3
CountryB
    CityC
```

Now If I double click Street1 then in event handler sender.SelectedItem is CountryA. Same happens if I double click CityA or CityB. What's the problem?

Comment: i cann´t reproduce what you described. Do you defined any additional binding on the TreeView. What else are you doing in the MouseDoubleClick method

Comment: I have followed MVVM. But for selected Item I am using event handlers. Is that the problem?

Comment: I can only reproduce what you describe when i click somewhere next to the Text (White space) of an TreeViewItem. If i double click exactly on the Text the SelectedItem is correct.

Comment: I tried to debug. I added another event for selected changed event. Now when I double click child node, then SelecteionChangedEvent hits two times. One is for child and second for the root.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, with an example as simple as what you described.
I had to add a cast for sender though, or it wouldn't compile.

```
var selectedItem = (sender as TreeView).SelectedItem;
```

If you did this, then the problem must be somewhere else. Do you have anything else in your code that might be the source of the problem ?

Comment: Problem is something else. Something is wrong with my model. Figuring it out.